# check if clicked href has a hash and do nothing else go to link

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.Home_Offer a', function(e){
    jQuery('a[href*="#"]').each(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
     });
});
```

I have the above code but it returns in Console.Log

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'preventDefault'

I am trying to stop hashed links from being clickable when the link is clicked. Some links have values where the `#` but when there is a `#` it needs to do nothing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If need to test the clicked anchor element(`this`)

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.Home_Offer a', function (e) {
    if (/#/.test(this.href)) {
    //if ($(this).is('[href*="#"]')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The `each()` callback receives the index and item as the arguments, so `e` inside the click handler is an int value which does not have the `preventDefault` method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying a separate function, you might try including  `onclick="return false"` with the link itself.

Alternately, if you're using jQuery to fire on a clickable part of the page that doesn't link through to somewhere else, you could use a css selector to target the desired div to fire onClick whatever you want to happen and change the cursor to pointer with css for the clickable div if you're trying to maintain that UI.

In general, I like to use the # for testing, but it doesn't necessarily play well with SEO or bots